# Twilio Skip Options (ruby)

Tags: ruby, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am building a web app using ruby and the twilio api that allows you to call a twilio number and record a voice recording.

This is the method that gets called to record your voice:

```
 def getRecord()
    Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |response|
      // userResponse = response.Gather --> does this Gather anything someone types at anytime?
      response.Say "Hello"
      response.Say "Record your message.", :voice => 'woman'
      response.Record :maxLength => '5', :trim => "trim-silence", :playBeep => "false", :action => '/feed', :method => 'get'
    end.text
  end
```

How do I add in "easter egg" function such as "skip the Say messages" or even, run a complete different method depending on what Digits the user hits. I tried adding the following `if` statement right after my `response.Record` call, and it does work, although it only works if the user hits `*` after the Recording starts and I want it to work starting from the moment the call starts.

```
  if userResponse['Digits'] == "*"
    getFeed()
  end
```

I also tried the following:

```
 def getRecord()
    Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |response|
      // userResponse = response.Gather --> does this Gather anything someone types at anytime?
     until userResponse == '*' do
      response.Say "Hello"
      response.Say "Record your message.", :voice => 'woman'
      response.Record :maxLength => '5', :trim => "trim-silence", :playBeep => "false", :action => '/feed', :method => 'get'
     end
     if userResponse == '*'
       getFeed()
     end

    end.text
  end
```

but this way nothing within the `until` loop runs at all.

How do I achieve adding a `response.Gather` that listens to whatever the user types in at any time during the call?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio and I think I can help here.

Taking your original method as an example, you can do the following:

```
def getRecord()
  Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |response|
    response.Gather :finishOnKey => '*' do
      response.Say "Hello"
      response.Say "Record your message.", :voice => 'woman'
      response.Record :maxLength => '5', :trim => "trim-silence", :playBeep => "false", :action => '/feed', :method => 'get'
    end
    # Whatever you want to happen when the user presses *
    getFeed()
  end.text
end
```

As you can see, you can nest [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) within a Gather block. In this case, Gather will listen to key presses. If a user presses * while the messages or the recording is going on, it will jump to the end of the Gather verb and continue with the TwiML after Gather, in this case calling the method `getFeed`. You might want to just have it redirect to your feed endpoint, and you could use `response.Redirect '/feed', :method => 'get'` for that.

Let me know if this helps.